# Angular Material autocomplete should call API each time and display suggestions

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-material

I need to call api after typing two letters in input field and it should show me the dropdown, If I type one more letter, it should call another API. I'm having issue in binding and making dynamic API. As of now searchTerm is foo only. I need to change searchTerm each time according to input field

service.ts file:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Client, CLIENT_TOKEN } from 'projects/vhap/src/public-api';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Item, Items } from './model';

const httpOptions =  {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'sometoken'
  })
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BetaService {
  private readonly searchingsubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private apiUrl = 'eval/api/Test/GetSearchAutoSuggests'
  /**
   *
   */
  readonly searching$ = this.searchingsubject
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(CLIENT_TOKEN) private readonly client: Client
  ) {}

 

  /**
   *
   * @param searchTerm
   * @param count
   * @returns
   */
  public getSearchAutoSuggests(
    searchTerm: string,
    count: number
  ): Observable<Items> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}?searchTerm=${searchTerm}&count=${count}`
    return this.http.get<Items>(url, httpOptions);
  }
 
}
```

ts file:
//not sure how to use switchMap and bind FormControl

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BetaService } from '../beta.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { tap, startWith, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-find',
  templateUrl: './find.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./find.component.scss']
})
export class FindComponent implements OnInit {
myControl = new FormControl();
beta: BetaService;
searchTerm = 'foo';
count = 10;
newData: any = [];
filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private betaService: BetaService) {
    this.beta = betaService;
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
  
      switchMap(() => {
       
      }) 
    )
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  
  showConfig() {
    this.betaService.getSearchAutoSuggests(this.searchTerm, this.count)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      let item  = data.Items;
      item.map((val) => {
        this.newData.push(val);
        return this.newData
      })

    });

  }
}
```

//HTML File

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of newData | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(400),
  //ignore search terms that have less than 2 characters, also handling stripping out whitepsaces
  filter( (searchTerm: string) => searchTerm.trim().length > 1) 
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap( (searchTerm: string) => {
    // now we switch observables to your service. i.e. "switchmap)
    // switchmap handles cancelling the previous pending request for the new one. ensuring the user doesn't see old data as they typehead
    return this.betaService.getSearchAutoSuggests(searchTerm, this.count)
  }) 
).subscribe( {
  next: (result: Items) => {
    // at this point, you have your 'items' array returned.
    // you can store it where you like
    this.newData = result;
  }
})
```

I observed that your template is using the `| async` pipe on the `newData` array. and this has a datatype of `any`. that is not recommended as it will cause readability issues in the long term.

with the changes above, the `newData` array is being updated based on the results of the http request for each keyword search, so you can get rid of the the `| async` pipe.

alternative, if you wanted to use the `| async` pipe to avoid managing subscriptions in the template, yould need to remove the subscription from your component and modify your template to be

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
  {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

but this is last note is an observation, not a requirement.

Comment: Argument of type '{ next: (result: any[]) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Items) => void'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'next' does not exist in type '(value: Items) => void'.ts(2345). I'm getting this error after using subscribe with next

Comment: updated response, there was an extra `(` in the next for the observer.

Comment: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more. Getting this for  this.filteredOptions